# RailsTutorial Chapter 8 wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, railstutorial.org

I'm stuck in the end of Chapter 8 where I'm getting the following error message:

> test_authenticated?_should_return_false_for_a_user_with_nil_digest#UserTest ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
>
> app/models/user.rb:36:in `authenticated?'
>
> test/models/user_test.rb:65:in `block in '

The tutorial says that I should get pass it (Green). Would appreciate your assistance

> user.rb file is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :remember_token
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

   # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end
end
```

> user_test.rb is (64-66):

```
test "authenticated? should return false for a user with nil digest" do
        assert_not @user.authenticated?(:remember, '')
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined the `authenticated?` method to accept a single parameter:

```
def authenticated?(remember_token)
```

And yet your test is calling it with two:

```
@user.authenticated?(:remember, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `authenticated?` method signature takes one argument as is evident from

```
def authenticated?(remember_token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end
```

But you're passing in 2. 
This bit below...

```
test "authenticated? should return false for a user with nil digest" do
        assert_not @user.authenticated?(:remember, '')
end
```

should be

```
test "authenticated? should return false for a user with nil digest" do
        assert_not @user.authenticated?(:remember)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found right answer - Listing 8.43:
Should be

```
test "authenticated? should return false for a user with nil digest" do
    assert_not @user.authenticated?('')
end
```

Do not copy code from github of Michael Hartl , there are too many inconsistencies between website and repo.

Comment: But any way first post help me to find the mistake